# INSERT current date or time into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If I create a table with an entity that is suppose to be `DATE` and when I `Insert` and leave that column blank shouldn't it display the current date? Same with time?

For example...

```
CREATE TABLE Register
(
Name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Date DATE,
Time TIME
);
```

Then I Insert:

```
INSERT INTO Register (Name)
VALUES ('Howard');
```

I want it to display on the table:

```
Howard | 5/6/2014 | 8:30 PM
```

But instead it displays:

```
Howard | NULL | NULL
```

Is this incorrect and if so what am I suppose to `Insert` to allow the current date and time of insert to display?

Comment: You need to have default constraint on table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Firstly***, you should have a `PRIMARY KEY` in your table.

***Secondly***, you have not set default values for columns `Date` and `Time`. Also, you can't set them separately for the `DATE` and `TIME` types – you should use `TIMESTAMP` type and `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` like :

```
 CREATE TABLE Register (
    Name CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );
```

***Thirdly***, if you want to use exactly two columns for date storing, you can set a trigger on `INSERT` event for this table, like it is shown below :

```
 CREATE TRIGGER default_date_time
 BEFORE INSERT ON my_table_name
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET NEW.Date = CURDATE();
    SET NEW.Time = CURTIME();
 END;
 $$
```

Comment: @JakeGould : I think this approach is a bit artificial for OP's purpose, however, it is up to him. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` method seems more elegant to me)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options:

1. Get rid of `Date` and `Time` columns and add `time stamp`

   `INSERT INTO Register (Name,Ctime) VALUES ('Howard',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`
2. If you want to continue with your table structure

   `INSERT INTO Register (Name,`Date`,`Time`) VALUES ('Howard',CURDATE(), CURTIME());`

Also Note that `date` and `time` are reserved words of MySQL and hence should be quoted with backticks to avoid conflicting with reserved words. Or just rename it according to a `table name` format.

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP solve my problem to insert the current date on my .sql script, I am using mysql 5.7.19

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a default. So you might think you could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE Register
(
Name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
Time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);
```

But that won’t work. You need to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and change your DB structure to use the combined `TIMESTAMP` format:

```
CREATE TABLE Register
(
Name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The reason being is there is no MySQL `DEFAULT` value for `DATE` or `TIME` alone. Some clues to [that behavior here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. **With one exception, the default value must**
>   **be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.** This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. **The exception**
>   **is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a**
>   **TIMESTAMP column.** See Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and
>   Updating for TIMESTAMP”.